# Realbasic OS X: find resource directory

Tags: macos, resources, realbasic

I'm storing a data file in the resource directory of a RealBasic app. But how do I programmatically locate it?

I've looked through the SpecialFolder classes, but found nothing useful.

The app will be OS X only, so I don't need to take care of multiplatform issues.

Thanks!

Yvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try app.executablefile.parent.parent.child("Resources")

Answer (score 1):

If you have the MonkeyBread Software plugins you can use this:

```
  dim f as FolderItem 
  f = app.BundleResourceFolderMBS
```

which I think is much easier to understand.

Comment: I don't have them, they're waaay to expensive for me :(